# Numeros negativos al descontar articulos del carrito de compra

Tags: javascript, vue.js

estoy haciendo un carrito de compra para una tienda online, y tengo problemas al desarrollar la lógica del carrito de compra.
Yo tengo N cantidad de productos... Producto A, Producto B, Producto C, Producto N....
con las siguientes atributos
id: n..,
titulo: Producto N,
precio: 10,
Cada vez que que se necesite n producto se agrega al carrito, cuando se agrega al carrito existe dos botones, uno con la funcion de aumentar la cantidad del producto, y el otro para disminutor la cantidad.
El problema que tengo es cuando tengo varios articulos agregados e intento disminuir la cantidad de productos, este se pasa a numeros negativos,
Ejemplo:
Agrego el producto A y B
A = 10;
B = 2;

A X 1
B X 1
Total = 22

que pasa si se disminuye la cantidad de A 2 veces el total queda -8, y no es la idea, lo idea seria que quede en 0 al eliminar elementos del carrito.

intente agregarle un condicional al boton de disminuir pero no funciono.

```
  dec: function (item) {
    if (this.total >= 0) {
      item.qty--;
      this.total = this.total - item.price;
    } else {
    }
  },
```

Cual puede ser el problema al desarrollar la logica de este problema? que me recomiendan realizar?

```
    <div id="app">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <img src="public/logo.png" />
        <h1>{{titlePage}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main container">
    <div class="products">
      <div
        v-for="product in products"
        class="product"
        v-bind:key="product.id"
      >
        <div>
          <h4 class="produc-title">{{product.title}}</h4>
          <button class="add-to-cart btn" v-on:click="addToCart(product)">
            Agregar a carrito
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in cart" v-bind:key="item.id" class="cart-item">
          <div class="item-title">{{item.title}}</div>
          <span class="item-qty">{{item.price}} x {{item.qty}}</span>
          <button v-on:click="inc(item)">+</button>
          <button v-on:click="dec(item)">-</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div v-if="cart.length >= 1" class="cart-total">
        Total: ${{total}}
      </div>
      <div v-else class="empty-cart">No items in the cart</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
  let vueApp = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      titlePage: "Vue.js Shop",
      total: 0,
      products: [
        { title: "product A", id: 1, price: 10 },
        { title: "product B", id: 2, price: 2 },
        { title: "product C", id: 3, price: 1 },
      ],
      cart: [],
    },
    methods: {
      addToCart: function (product) {
        let x = this.cart;
        let y = typeof x;
        console.log(y);
        console.log("ssss");

        //
        this.total += product.price;
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
          if (this.cart[i].id === product.id) {
            this.cart[i].qty++;
            found = true;
          }
        }
        if (!found) {
          this.cart.push({
            id: product.id,
            price: product.price,
            title: product.title,
            qty: 1,
          });
        }
        //console.log(this.total);
        //console.log(product.title);
        //console.log(this.cart);
      },
      inc: function (item) {
        item.qty++;
        this.total = item.price + this.total;
      },
      dec: function (item) {
        if (this.total >= 0) {
          item.qty--;
          this.total = this.total - item.price;
        } else {
        }
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Si vas a reducir cantidad, entonces compara cantidad y no total: `if (item.qty > 0)`

Comment: @Triby  <3 gracias!!!!!!! exactamente eso es lo que tenia que hacer, comparar la cantidad y si es >0 disminuyele la cantidad al elemento[i]

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en el primer segmento de código:

```js
 dec: function (item) {
    if (this.total >= 0) {
      item.qty--;
      this.total = this.total - item.price;
    } else {
    }
  },
```

En la cláusula `if` estás preguntando si total es mayor o IGUAL que 0. Por lo que cuando la cantidad es 0, te permite reducirlo hasta -1. Lo correcto sería solo dejar reducir la cantidad si esta es MAYOR que 0.

```js
 dec: function (item) {
    if (this.total > 0) {
      item.qty--;
      this.total = this.total - item.price;
    }
  },
```